# How to populate a control inside a DataTemplate whenever the template is instantiated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have an `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` describing how to display each item. The UI I'd like to have inside the DataTemplate is a [bad fit to be modelled by XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117219/how-to-build-a-grid-of-controls-in-xaml) and I am going to have to populate a `Grid` in code.

How do I get this code to run every time my `DataTemplate` is instantiated, so that I get a chance to populate the bits I couldn't express in XAML?

---

To expand a little, consider a simplified example. The VM looks like this:

```
class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyGrid Grid { get; set; } // describes a complex grid-like model
}
```

The `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Grid/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `<Grid/>` is the thing I want to populate in code based on `MyItem.Grid`. How can I do this?

(If you are going to say that I shouldn't populate the `<Grid/>` in code but just use XAML, please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117219/how-to-build-a-grid-of-controls-in-xaml) instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily hook the `Loaded` event on the `Grid`.

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
```

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, ....)
{
    var grid = (Grid)sender;
    var item = (MyItem)grid.DataContext;
    //Go time
}
```